# Why do I get a segmentation fault for my operator +?

Tags: c++

I have this simple code :

```
vector<double> operator+(const vector<double>& v1, const vector<double>& v2) {
        int n = v1.size();
        vector<double> a(n);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
                a[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
        }
        return a;
}
```

But my debugger shows me that there is a segmentation fault, I don't understand why

Comment: You should check that the vectors are the same size.

Comment: Thank you. If i understand, I have somewhere in my code 2 vector that doesn't have the same size with this operator +. Isn't it ?

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the function and see if you can get more information.

Comment: To test that, drop something like `if (v1.size() != v2.size()) { throw std::runtime_error("Vector size mismatch!"); }` at the beginning of the operator and pop a breakpoint on the `throw`. You can use the backtrace to help narrow in on the villain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `operator+` *assumes* both `vector`s are the same size.  If `v1` is larger than `v2`, the loop will go out of bounds of `v2`, causing **undefined behavior**.

So, either validate the sizes are equal, eg:

```cpp
vector<double> operator+(const vector<double>& v1, const vector<double>& v2) {
    size_t n = v1.size();
    if (n != v2.size()) {
        throw ...; // or return ...
    }
    vector<double> a(n);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        a[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
    }
    return a;
}
```

Or else, rewrite the logic to support adding `vector`s of different sizes, eg:

```cpp
vector<double> operator+(const vector<double>& v1, const vector<double>& v2) {
    size_t v1size = v1.size(), v2size = v2.size();
    size_t n = std::min(v1size, v2size);
    size_t m = std::max(v1size, v2size);
    vector<double> a(m);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        a[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
    }
    if (n < m) {
        vector<double> &b = (v1size < v2size) ? v2 : v1;
        for(size_t i = n; i < m; ++i){
            a[i] = b[i];
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone !